# Focus lost immediately after loading form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I am using below code in javascript to set focus on control.

```js
Xrm.Page.getControl("controlid").setFocus(true);
```

It's working fine on some form.

Issue : Now When I am loading the focus come to the control but lost immediately.

I am not able to locate right solution for ? Anyone provide me the hint on this front

I have also tried with

```js
document.getElementById("controlid").focus();
```

Same issue arise with this as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried applying the focus after onLoad() event?

Comment: Means I have set focus at the end of onLoad event ? but not working ...After Onload means can you give me the example

Comment: In some cases where I need focus but it's being stolen, I find that using a setTimeout() can work just fine. Usually a timeout of 100ms, give or take, isn't really enough for a user to notice the jump

Answer (score 1):

As @trnelson said, this can be accomplished with a setTimeout call in JavaScript. Here's an example:

```
setTimeout(function(){ Xrm.Page.getControl("controlid").setFocus(true);}, 200);
```